# Simulating BlueROV2 with Gazebo 11 in ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic

Tags: ros-noetic, gazebo-simulator

I’m trying to simulate bluerov2 with gazebo 11 in ubuntu 20.04 in ros noetic.

I tried the famous [bluerov_ros_playground](https://github.com/patrickelectric/bluerov_ros_playground) but it's not working as it should.
My guess is that [freefloating_gazebo](https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/freefloating_gazebo) is not properly installed. The github creator does not provide any installation guide so I'm not sure I did the process correctly. 
When I start the gazebo the bluerov just falls down and never really float.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Michail Chatzispyrou. I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking because you haven't made any statements about specific errors or troubleshooting steps you've taken to resolve your issues. You state that bluerov_ros_playground is "not working as it should," and state that you think freefloating_gazebo is not properly installed. Why do you think that? What steps have you taken to resolve that concern?

Comment: You state that the github creator has not provided any installation guide but [the readme](https://github.com/patrickelectric/bluerov_ros_playground/blob/master/README.md) gives a full list of prerequisites, installation steps, and instructions on how to run it. Again, you mention `freefloating_gazebo` is not properly installed, but it's listed as a requirement for bluerov_ros_playground. Please *edit your question* to include all steps you've tried in the instructions, to clarify if you have the prerequisites installed correctly, and to detail any other troubleshooting steps you've taken.

Comment: Hello, 
I start the gazebo the simulation in pause, when I unpause the bluerov falls down and never float in order to achieve freefloating

Comment: Right, you are seeing issues with buoyancy and you think freefloating_gazebo is not installed correctly. Why do you think that? What have you done to fix it? Have you successfully run any of the [freefloating_gazebo_demo](https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/freefloating_gazebo_demo) content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of `freefloating-gazebo`. It is not maintained anymore since many other packages now simulate hydrodynamics and thrusters through Gazebo plugins. They also have much better names than my initial package!

Anyway, the installation is quite straightforward as it is a ROS package. Besides the ROS dependencies, it depends on the Gazebo libs and Eigen headers. Cloning the repo inside a ROS 1 workspace and running `catkin build` should do the trick.

Note that as we are in 2024 I would suggest simulating the BlueROV2 with ROS 2 and the "new" Gazebo. We use the [package here](https://github.com/CentraleNantesROV/bluerov2) but I am sure there are many other instances of BlueROV2 models with modern Gazebo plugins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the package worked only if I cloned it inside the src folder of a workspace. However, I will try simulating it in ROS 2. Do you have any other suggestions about bluerov2 in ROS 2?

Comment: Well I would start with the repo that is linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install all package dependencies ?

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

Comment: Yes `michael@michael-linux:~/free_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r
#All required rosdeps installed successfully`